# how to set every rows primary key for sub Query

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am new in mysql. please help

I want to user current row post id to   use in sub query for count.
What should I use in the place of  "current_row_post_id" in the query

`SELECT post_id, title, description, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_reacts WHERE react_type_id = 1 AND posts.post_id = ? current_row_post_id ) AS total_love, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts_reacts WHERE react_type_id = 2 AND posts.post_id = ? current_row_post_id) AS total_tanks FROM posts;`

posts table description:

```
+--------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|Field         |Type           |Null|Key|Default          |Extra                                        |
+--------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|post_id       |bigint unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL             |auto_increment                               |
|post_type     |varchar(20)    |NO  |   |NULL             |                                             |
|title         |varchar(256)   |YES |   |NULL             |                                             |
|description   |text           |YES |   |NULL             |                                             |
|group_id      |bigint unsigned|YES |   |NULL             |                                             |
|shared_post_id|bigint unsigned|YES |   |NULL             |                                             |
|user_id       |bigint unsigned|NO  |   |NULL             |                                             |
|created_at    |timestamp      |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|DEFAULT_GENERATED                            |
|updated_at    |timestamp      |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+--------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

posts_reacts table description:

```
+-------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|Field        |Type           |Null|Key|Default          |Extra                                        |
+-------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|post_react_id|bigint unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL             |auto_increment                               |
|post_id      |bigint unsigned|NO  |MUL|NULL             |                                             |
|user_id      |bigint unsigned|NO  |   |NULL             |                                             |
|react_type_id|int            |NO  |   |NULL             |                                             |
|created_at   |timestamp      |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|DEFAULT_GENERATED                            |
|updated_at   |timestamp      |NO  |   |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
+-------------+---------------+----+---+-----------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the table name `posts_reacts`

```
AND posts.post_id = posts_reacts.post_id
```

or the sub-query aliases `total_love` and `total_tanks`

```
AND posts.post_id = total_love.post_id
AND posts.post_id = total_tanks.post_id
```

to qualify the ambiguous column `post_id`. Make sure to remove `current_row_post_id` as you can't have a new column alias in the *where* clause.